# Laptop does not detect USB monitor

Tags: windows, laptop, usb, multiple-monitors

I have an AOC E1670SW USB monitor that I want to connect to my Windows 10 installed laptop.

When connected, the monitor powers up but shows "No Signal" message. The laptop is unable to detect any external monitor. I have tried the `Fn + F4 and Shift + F4` key combination but that also does not work.

I have also tried installing DisplyLink software and the drivers(only .icm and .inf files available).

Answer (score 0):

The USB connection is for power only.  You still need to connect a VGA cable for the video signal.

Comment: Oops! I just realised that. My bad.